# proftpd change default directory

Tags: permissions, directory

I just installed Proftpd on my debian server. Now I need to change the default directory.
When I connect I start in my home folder. This is incorrect.
I changed the DefaultRoot to /usr/share/nginx/www but still when I connect I start in home.
So basically how do I change the directory I start in when I connect?

Answer (score 0):

Had to set permissions and use a group for the user in question.